# Terraform: Invalid value for string parameter - Variable Validation Syntax

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have the following terraform code for creating an Azure resource group using a map(object). I was attempting to also put in some validation conditions to the variable, but it errors out saying

```
│ Error: Invalid function argument
│ 
│   on variables.tf line 11, in variable "resource_groups":
│   11:     condition     = length(var.resource_groups["name"]) >= 1 && length(var.resource_groups["name"]) <= 90 && length(regexall("[^\\w()-.]", var.resource_groups["name"])) == 0
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.resource_groups["name"] is a object, known only after apply
│ 
│ Invalid value for "string" parameter: string required.
╵
╷
│ Error: Invalid function argument
│ 
│   on variables.tf line 16, in variable "resource_groups":
│   16:     condition     = substr(var.resource_groups["name"], 0, 3) == "rg-"
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.resource_groups["name"] is a object, known only after apply
│ 
│ Invalid value for "str" parameter: string required.
```

**CODE**

```
variable "resource_groups" {
  description = "A map of Resource groups and their properties."
  type = map(object({
    name     = string
    location = string
    tags     = map(string)
  }))

  validation {
    condition     = length(var.resource_groups["name"]) >= 1 && length(var.resource_groups["name"]) <= 90 && length(regexall("[^\\w()-.]", var.resource_groups["name"])) == 0
    error_message = "The resource group name must be betweem 1 and 90 characters, using alphanumerics, underscores, parentheses, hyphens, periods."
  }

  validation {
    condition     = substr(var.resource_groups["name"], 0, 3) == "rg-"
    error_message = "The resource group name must start with \rg-\"."
  }
}
```

Can we not use validation when using map(object)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `map(object)` is enumerable/iterable and contains an arbitrary key, so you must likewise validate on the iterated values, and ignore the unknown key:

```
validation {
  condition     = alltrue([for rg in var.resource_groups : length(rg.name) >= 1 && length(rg.name) <= 90 && length(regexall("[^\\w()-.]", rg.name)) == 0])
  error_message = "The resource group name must be betweem 1 and 90 characters, using alphanumerics, underscores, parentheses, hyphens, periods."
}

validation {
  condition     = alltrue([for rg in var.resource_groups : substr(rg.name, 0, 3) == "rg-"])
  error_message = "The resource group name must start with \rg-\"."
}
```

Comment: wow, ok. I will try that out and see how it works. Thanks.